# XAML Get Item text value from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I have a ListView Control witch item is composite by two TextBlocks like that:

```
        <ListView x:Name="resultsList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="470" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="342" FontSize="21.333" BorderThickness="0" ItemClick="RedirectPage" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,-4,0,-4">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Text="{Binding target_name}" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{Binding type_name}" Opacity="30" Margin="0, 0, 0 ,30"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In the code behind I am trying to get as string the text value from first TextBlock element.

```
string targetName;

targetName = resultsList.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

I want that Variable "targetName" то assign the text value ( Text="{Binding target_name}" ) from first TextBlock in the ListView Item.

I will be very thankful if someone is able to help me.

Comment: do you have some knowledge about MVVM?

Comment: you can retrieve this value very easily if you opt to use MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resultsList.SelectedItem should be the object from the collection that is bound to the ListView. So, you can just cast it to the appropriate type and then access the target_name member

Answer (score 1):

Itemssource should be collection. You need to typecast the collection to get the value.

`class listData
    {
       public string target_name { get; set; }
       public string type_name{ get; set; }
    }`

You can get values like this

```
  listData ld= (listData)resultsList.SelectedItem;
  string  targetName =ld.target_name;
```